# Structuring a user rating/rebuttal system

Tags: 7, comments, nodes, rating

I am looking to create a really basic rating system (user reference and fivestar content type). But I would like to be able to have users [rebut](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rebut) ratings if need be. I am just trying to figure out, structurally, how to do it. Would I have to create another content type called [rebuttal](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rebuttal) and reference the rating? What about adding a field to the rating content type with the ability for the referenced user to fill in a text field? Limit comment access to just the rating author and the referenced user?

This may be the wrong forum to ask this, since its an open ended and subjective question. But I guess my question would be "How would you allow users to make selective edits to a node or limit comments to only the node author or referenced user?"

Comment: This is an English-speaking website @Pierre.Vriens, you should expect English words to be used, regardless of your own linguistic background. Non-English speakers most certainly should expect to need a dictionary here, that's a given. There's no reason to ask people to dumb down their posts, Google will easily translate this for you if you're struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to create a **[Rebut](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rebut)** flag, but do NOT make it a 'global' flag though. The flag is to be created (configured) by an admin, but each user (authorized to use the flag) will then be able to "rebut rating" using such flag. If it would make sense, you may want to have multiple flags configured for this (eg: Rebut-low , Rebut-medium, Rebut-high, whatever that would "mean" in your case).

Then create a view (with the [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) for each flag, whereas you create a "views relationship" with such flag(s).

If you're not familiar with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, checkout the [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the flag module.

You might also want to look at some of the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) related modules, such as (partial list):

- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), to create lists of flagged content, users, etc, such as in the video about [Creating global flags and listing flagged content in Views](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/creating-global-flags-and-listing-flagged-content-in-views).
- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), to trigger rules for anything that is flagged, such as in the video about [Triggering rules with Flag](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/triggering-rules-with-flag), or to set flags with the Rules module, such as in the video about [Setting flags with Rules](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/setting-flags-with-rules).

Refer to Flag's [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag) for (way) more details.

**Note**: Via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) it should be possibly to add logic to verify the "usage" of such flag.

Comment: That is an interesting take on this. I would however have to look into only showing the flag if a user has been referenced on the node. Thanks for the suggestion.